# How get css class content in Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following CSS class:

```
.test{
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  color: white;
}
```

Is there possible that we can store in a JS variable the content of **.test** class? something like this:

```
myTestClass = "{background:red;position:absolute;display:flex;color: white;}";
```

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: Why do you need this result, what problem are you trying to solve? Is it for all elements in the DOM, or just one particular element, or for all classes, or one specific class? Please see the guidance on "*[ask]*."

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules

Answer (score 0):

i can imagine it works if your css is in a style tag.

something like

```
document.querySelector("style").textContent.match('.test {(.*?)}')
```

but i don't know of any way to extract css from a css file.
I mean... if you want to store the actual content of your css there. To me it isn't fully clear what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

just use window.getComputedStyle

```
const test = document.getElementById('test')
const style = window.getComputedStyle(test)

const myTestClass = {
  background:style.backgroundColor
}
```